# Integral of product of error function and Gaussian

Tags: integration, substitution, gaussian-integral, error-function

I found the following relation from [a 1968 paper](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73b/jresv73bn1p1_a1b.pdf):

$
\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\erf(x)\exp^{-(ax+b)^2}dx=-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{a}\erf\big(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\big), Re(a^2)>0,
$

where $\erf(x)$ is the error function, and $a$ and $b$ constants that do not depend on $x$.

Alternatively, [here's a screenshot of relevant equation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVyYW.png)

My question is: is this valid complex constants $a$ and $b$? The condition on $a$ suggests so, but nothing is said about $b$.

Furthermore, to put the integral I really wish to solve into the form above, I made the definition $t + z \equiv x$, where $t$ is real but $z$ is complex. Is that a legitimate move? I worry because $\erf(z)$ for complex $z$ blows up.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is valid for $\operatorname{Re} a^2 > 0$ and any complex $b$. Suppose $a$ is fixed. The integral converges uniformly in $b$ on any compact set, therefore it's an entire function of $b$. The rhs is also an entire function of $b$, so the two functions coincide. It's also true that the integral over $(-\infty, \infty)$ is the same as the integral over $(-\infty + i \gamma, \infty + i \gamma)$. Since $\operatorname{erf}(A + i \gamma) - \operatorname{erf}(A) = 2/\sqrt \pi \int_A^{A + i \gamma} e^{-z^2} dz$, the integrals over $[\pm A, \pm A + i \gamma]$ tend to zero.

Comment: @Maxim It is reassuring to see this, but I'm not sure I understand the logic. Do you think you could try to dumb it down for a physicist to understand?

Comment: Regarding the first part: we establish that the lhs of your identity is analytic in $\mathbb C$ as a function of $b$ and the rhs is also analytic in $\mathbb C$. We know that they coincide on the real axis. Then they coincide everywhere by the identity theorem. Regarding the second part: the integral over $[-A, A, A + i \gamma, -A + i \gamma, -A]$ is zero by the Cauchy integral theorem. The integrals over the vertical segments are small because the exponential is small and $\operatorname{erf}(\pm A + i y)$ is very close to $\operatorname{erf}(\pm A)$, which is very close to $\pm 1$.

Comment: Hello @Maxim, I would like to give you credit for your response to this post. Please reply so we can get in touch.